# Spell checking library for Windows Mobile 6.x

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, spell-checking

We are looking into how we can check the spelling of text entered by the user in an app we have developed.

Is there any standard APIs and libraries/dictionaries included in the Windows Mobile 6.x OS that can be used for this? Please point me in the rigth direction if there is.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows Mobile 6 has Auto Correction and Auto Suggestion built in.  You can enable and disable these from your app with the following PInvoke call.

```
 public static class InputContext
    {
        private enum SHIC_FEATURE : uint
        {
            RESTOREDEFAULT = 0,
            AUTOCORRECT = 1,
            AUTOSUGGEST = 2,
            HAVETRAILER = 3,
            CLASS = 4
        }

        [DllImport("aygshell.dll")]
        private static extern int SHSetInputContext(IntPtr hwnd, SHIC_FEATURE dwFeature, ref bool lpValue);

        public static void SetAutoSuggestion(IntPtr handle, bool enable)
        {
            SHSetInputContext(handle, SHIC_FEATURE.AUTOSUGGEST, ref enable);
            SHSetInputContext(handle, SHIC_FEATURE.AUTOCORRECT, ref enable);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Great, thanks! We will try it in a while. I'll get back for comment, etc. when done.

Comment: Hi. I'm using this with Resco touch-controls. The problem is that the autosuggest control that appears is too small to select using a finger. Anyone know how to make it bigger? Thanks, Mark.